# Merging trunk into a branch that has local changes

Tags: svn

I have a branch in SVN that I want to update with new changes from the trunk. I also have some files with local changes in this branch. I do not want to commit some of these changes just yet.

If I try to merge the changes from trunk into this branch, it gives me an error:

```
Error: Cannot merge into a working copy that has local modifications
```

Is there a way to merge the trunk into the branch remotely on the server, so I can just update the branch normally afterwards?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is ***highly recommended*** that you use a ***clean*** and ***up to date*** copy of the working directory for merging.

However, if you want to break these cardinal rules and *shoot yourself in the foot*, Subversion gives you the means and the bullets:

```
$ svn merge --force --allow-mixed-revisions $repo_url
```

The `--allow-mixed-revisions` parameter will allow a merge to take place even if there are mixed revisions in the working copy. The `--force` parameter will allow you to merge even if there are local changes.

There's actually a few scenarios where using `--force` might be a good idea, but I can't think of any reason at all for `--allow-mixed-revisions`.

Comment: Unfortunately --force doesn't work with --reintegrate

Comment: The `--reintegrate` flag completely changes the way the merge works. The merge changes from a three-way merge to a mere two-way merge. The main purpose is to force the _development stream_ you're working on to match the _development stream_ you're merging from. You can't use mixed revisions because it won't make any sense, and you must have a clean checkout. Newer versions of the Subversion client attempt to see whether a merge is a _reintegration merge_ and eliminate the need for the `--reintegrate` flag.

Answer (score 6):

No. You must go through the merge process on a working copy, resolve the potential conflicts, and commit.

But the working copy could be a different working copy from the one you're currently working on: just do a fresh checkout of the branch to a new directory, make the merge in this new directory and commit.

Comment: This worked for me. Merge into a clean check out, commit, then run an update on your branch with the local changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should first take update and commit to your **working directory** and after doing this you take update in **trunk directory** and then merge **trunk** with **working directory**